# how to exhaust memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

It might look silly, but I'm kind of confused about this now. Why this program won't consume all the memory?
For example: I have the following program running in a Linux(2G RAM) terminal,

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
     cout<<sizeof(int*)<<endl;
     for(int i=0; i<pow(2.0,30.0);i++)
       {
         new int(i);
       }
    return 1;
  }
```

1) I confirmed the int size in this machine is 4 bytes, then for 2GB ram, it can only hold 2^30/2^2=2^28

2) following the logic above, how could you change the program actually consume all the 2GB memory?

Added: I just want to make sure I understand it correctly theoreticaly. If there is no virtual memory or os optimization etc.., 2GBRAM only could hold 2^28 int, is that right? In that case, the above program will consume all memory? Do you know how I could turn off the virtual memory/swap memory features etc.. in a linux?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you really trying to do? If you want to test if your code works in low memory situations then you should really compile new version of new/delete that will throw exceptions at the appropriate time during your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculations seem suspect.

2<sup>20</sup> = 1,048,576
2<sup>11</sup> = 2,048

To allocate a billion integers, try 2<sup>30</sup>. Note that your `vector<int*>` will take a significant amount of space (at least as much as the integers you're allocating). To simply exhaust memory, you don't need that at all. You can call `new int(i)` and throw away the returned pointer, and the memory will still be allocated.

Remember also that your machine likely has virtual memory beyond the 2 GB physical RAM you have installed.

Comment: sure, 2^30 etc.. will work. I would like know the exact number based on the machine's RAM size, is it possible?

Comment: You've changed the question, which makes my answer somewhat less useful. However, you still seem to think that 2 GB = 2^11, which is clearly wrong by several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 7):

Because of virtual addressing, you can allocate more memory than you actually have in terms of RAM. The OS will automatically page out memory (to the hard drive) that you're not using. In this way, your RAM serves as a large cache to the hard disk's swap file, which represents the actual memory of your system.

Your *actual* limit is the address space of a pointer, which unless you're compiling for (and running on) a 64-bit platform is 32-bits. So you can allocate 4GB of space.

Comment: 64 bit machines are relatively common nowadays. So how much memory could that theoretically consume.

Comment: Don't most linux distros now enable PAE by default?

Comment: x86-64 implementations (CPUs) of today only allows pointers to use 48 bits (even though they are 64-bits in size; the other 24 are currently wasted). So that's 2^48, or 256 TB. Which is enough for a little while.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: PAE only impacts what the OS can access; 32-bit applications are still limited to a 32-bit virtual address space. The OS can access 36 bits, which allows 32-bit OS's to use 64GB of actual RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't do anything useful with its memory. The optimizer can therefore optimize it to:

```
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
     std::cout<<sizeof(int*)<<endl;
     for(int i=0; i<(1<<10);i++)
       {
         // nothing
       }
    return 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 GB is the same as two billion bytes. This means that your RAM can hold approximately 500 million int pointers. Now, your system also has a swap file for storage, which is probably as big as your RAM or bigger.

2 ^ 20 is about one million. So while your program eats some of your memory, it does not use it all up. Just increase that pow() call to a ridiculously large number, and it will work. Have fun!

Also: There is no guarantee that sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*), although it's true for many systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are some misconception on memory usage.

1. 2GB memory machine don't means you can only use 2GB memory. 
   (1) We have swap space ; (2) Linux overcommits.
2. `new int` does not take 4 byte.
   There are memory overhead
3. You can't use all the memory.
   Memory fragmentation, .text section, etc.. all take up memory space.

Comment: Re. point (1): A single process may only use 2GB. Swap space is only relevant when you consider (a) multiple processes or (b) a machine with less than (2GB + OS overhead) RAM.

Comment: @RobH,  On x86, Linux have 3:1 (3GB vm space for user mode, 1GB for kernel space) for many years. And, of course, you can have more on 64bit machine.  And single processor does not means you can use all memory (+os overhead), some memory can be `mlock` by other process.

Comment: I misread the question as stating that the machine had a 2:2 split. Doh!